# cannot import name LOOKUP_SEP

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and I'm trying to set up django-roa but when i'm trying to start my webserver I have this error `cannot import name LOOKUP_SEP`

If I remove `django_roa` from my INSTALLEDS_APP it's okay but I want django-roa working and I don't know how resolve this problem.

And I don't know what kind of detail I can tell to find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django_roa` is not yet compatible with django 1.5. I'm afraid it only works with django 1.3.

Comment: Indeed it's the reason. Do you know if there is something else for django 1.5 or i have to downgrade to django 1.3 ?

Answer (score 19):

This question is the top Google search result for "cannot import name LOOKUP_SEP", therefore although it doesn't necessarily solve any other compatibility issues between `django-roa` and Django 1.5 I want to point out...

You can solve this (specific) error by replacing:

```
from django.db.models.sql.constants import LOOKUP_SEP
```

with:

```
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP
```

Comment: Upvote for providing an actual answer, and not a workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded from 1.5.2 to 1.4.0 and my app started working again.  Via pip:

pip install django==1.4

Hope that helps.